# How to make the Image responsive for the desktop screens using Tailwind and nextJS?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a component to display a set of images with horizontal scroll. The images are displayed with width:125px and height:250px for mobile and tablet screens. And for the Desktop screens, I wish to have the width:250px and height:520px.

The code i tried is below :

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

const recentGameItems = [
 { id: 1, icon: '/images/slot1.png' },
 { id: 2, icon: '/images/slot2.png' },
 { id: 3, icon: '/images/slot3.png' },
 { id: 4, icon: '/images/slot1.png' },
 { id: 5, icon: '/images/slot2.png' },
 { id: 6, icon: '/images/slot3.png' },
 { id: 7, icon: '/images/slot1.png' },
];

const V2Layout: React.FC = () => {
  return (
  <div className="flex overflow-x-auto no-scrollbar overflow-y-hidden items-center">
  <div>
    <div
      className="flex list-none font-semibold text-white"
      style={{ width: `${recentGameItems.length * 125}px` }}
    >
      {recentGameItems.map(recentGameItem => (
        <div
          key={recentGameItem.id}
          className="flex flex-col px-1 items-center justify-center"
        >
          <div className="w-250 h-250 md:w-125 md:h-250 bg-yellow-200">
            <Image
              src={recentGameItem.icon}
              alt={`Menu Icon ${recentGameItem.id}`}
              width={125} // Width for mobile and tablet screens
              height={250} // Height for mobile and tablet screens
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

 export default V2Layout;
```

Can someone guide me to resolve this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the issue with the code you posted. But you might be confusing how the media queries work on tailwind you gotta go from small to big, defaul sizes are for small screens, md: for tablets and lg: for desktops and etc.

example:

```
<div class="w-[100px] h-[100px] md:w-[125px] md:h-[250px] lg:w-[200px] lg:h-[520px] bg-yellow-200"></div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/nKzOyiA9LY